# TestNG + Groups + BeforeGroups Running Methods in alphabetical order

Tags: testng

I have a number of groups, I would like to be able to run all or a subset in parallel e.g. -Dgroups=a,b,...  I have a method annotated with @BeforeGroups annotation that needs to do some behavior before a group is run.  The behavior I'm seeing though is when I run two specific groups one with three tests the other with two, the first two tests of the first group get run then the two tests of the second group then the last method of the first group. (in alphabetical order based on class names where the tests are defined)  The methods are spread across different classes.  Please help!

testng.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://beust.com/testng/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="API Tests">
    <test name="all">
        <groups>
            <run>
                <include name="a" />
                <include name="b" />
                <include name="c" />
                <include name="d" />
                <include name="e" />
            </run>
        </groups>
        <packages>
            <package name="package.*" />
        </packages>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Execution order (with abbreviations for obfuscation)

```
Class: E; Method: testF; Group: a
Class: I; Method: testI; Group: a
Class: S; Method: testSH; Group: b
Class: S; Method: testSI; Group: b
Class: T; Method: testF; Group: a
```

Note: I have tried setting threads to 1, this does not fix the order of the tests/groups execution.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to include the number of threads. If you have 2 groups & need to run them in 2 parallel threads, the XML would be -

```
<suite name="FooSuite" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">
<test name="Group1">
    <groups>
        <run>
            <include name="1" />
        </run>
    </groups>
    <packages>
        <package name="package.*" />
    </packages>
</test>
<test name="Group2">
    <groups>
        <run>
            <include name="2" />
        </run>
    </groups>
    <packages>
        <package name="package.*" />
    </packages>
</test>
```

Running in parallel is allowed for Tests, classes & methods. You could design your XML accordingly to suit your requirement.

Comment: This doesn't work.  The behavior I mentioned above with test execution still occurs.  I tried one thread with one test that had two groups in it with the same incorrect behavior.

Comment: That is expected behavior. If you tried one test with 2 groups in it it will run them serially one after the other since parallel flag is set on tests. Please try the one mentioned in my answer & then downgrade my answer

Comment: I did try with the same results, maybe I didn't understand your response.  I want to run two groups so i only included Group1And2 and set parallel="tests" thread-count="1".

Comment: I have now edited the answer to run 2 groups in parallel. Let me know if it works

Comment: My earlier answer contained the use case for this scenario - Group1And2, Group3 & Group4 will run in parallel. Tests under Group1And2 will run the Group1 1st & then Group2. Hope this clarifies

Comment: I'll undo the down vote, but this doesn't work for me.  My tests currently rely on @BeforeGroups that sets a static variable that the tests rely on.  If the two groups are running in different threads this will not work.

Comment: in that case, you could run the tests in parallel on "classes" if your @BeforeGroups & actual test groups reside in different classes. Instead of including the package name in your XML, include <class>

Comment: Didn't work either.  I've given up and implemented my own "groups" by using IHookable.  Thanks for your help.